# How to map a join to a join in Doctrine ORM native sql result set

Tags: php, join, orm, doctrine-orm

How to map a join to a join in Doctrine ORM native sql result set

I want a result set with entities that have a join to a join. When dumping the result set I see that the join isn't correct.
The join in the second entity in the result set is joined to the first entity. And the join in the second entity is null.
But if I leave out the mapping of a field of the deepest join, the joins will be correct (except of the missing field).

**relation**

```
MyEntity ----> FooEntity ----> BarEntity
```

**sql result**

```
id   some_field   foo_id   bar_id   my_field
1    testa        123      456      test1
1    testb        8823     998      test2
```

**mapping**

```
$rsm->addEntityResult('MyEntity', 'a');

// first join
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('FooEntity', 'foo', 'a', 'foo');

// join to the first join
$rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('BarEntity', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo');

$rsm->addFieldResult('a', 'id', 'id')
    ->addFieldResult('a', 'some_field', 'someField')
    ->addFieldResult('foo', 'foo_id', 'id')
    ->addFieldResult('bar', 'bar_id', 'id');
```

**print_r**

```
// if I disable this addFieldResult, the joins are correct, but myField === null
//$rsm->addFieldResult('bar', 'my_field', 'myField')

object(stdClass)[352]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'FooEntity' (length=42)
  public 'id' => int 123
  public 'bar' => 
    object(stdClass)[446]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'BarEntity' (length=49)
      public 'id' => string '456' (length=2)
      public 'myField' => null
object(stdClass)[352]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'FooEntity' (length=42)
  public 'id' => int 8823
  public 'bar' => 
    object(stdClass)[446]
      public '__CLASS__' => string 'BarEntity' (length=49)
      public 'id' => string '998' (length=2)
      public 'myField' => null

// if I enable this addFieldResult, the joins are incorrect
$rsm->addFieldResult('bar', 'my_field', 'myField');

object(stdClass)[352]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'FooEntity' (length=42)
  public 'id' => int 123
  public 'bar' => 
      object(stdClass)[446]                                      | 
          public '__CLASS__' => string 'BarEntity' (length=49)   | THE WRONG BarEntity
          public 'id' => string '998' (length=2)                 |
          public 'myField' => null                               |
object(stdClass)[352]
  public '__CLASS__' => string 'FooEntity' (length=42)
  public 'id' => int 8823
  public 'bar' => null                                           | IT SHOULD BE HERE
```

Thanks for any help

Richard

Comment: Solved it. It's all about the correct order of the field mappings. They must be in the same order as the sql. See [link](http://www.codeitive.com/0SJggWPWqj/doctrine2-native-query-rows-are-shifted.html)